# Crash when printing a tree in C++

Tags: c++

I am doing a university task, but I ran into a problem, I do not know how to correctly complete this task. Here is the code I wrote, but it does not work

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include "RootClass.h"
#include "ChildClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string rootName, parentName, childName;

    cin >> rootName;

    BaseClass* root = new RootClass(0, rootName);

    string temp;
    while (cin >> parentName >> childName, parentName != childName)
    {
        if (parentName == rootName)
            BaseClass* obj = new ChildClass(root, childName);
        else
        {
            temp = parentName;
            BaseClass* obj = new ChildClass(root, childName);
            obj->setName(parentName);
        }
    }

    cout << rootName << endl;
    root->printTree();
}
```

BaseClass.cpp

```
#include "BaseClass.h"

BaseClass::BaseClass(BaseClass* pParent)
{
    if (pParent != 0)
        children.push_back(pParent);
}

BaseClass::BaseClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name)
{
    pParent->setName(name);

    if (pParent != 0)
        children.push_back(pParent);
}

void BaseClass::setName(std::string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

std::string BaseClass::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void BaseClass::printTree()
{
    std::cout << name;

    for (const auto& i : children)
        std::cout << i->getName() << "  ";
}
```

RootClass.cpp

```
#include "RootClass.h"

RootClass::RootClass()
{

}

RootClass::RootClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name)
{
    BaseClass(pParent, name);
}
```

ChildClass.cpp

```
#include "RootClass.h"

RootClass::RootClass()
{

}

RootClass::RootClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name)
{
    BaseClass(pParent, name);
}
```

BaseClass.h

```
#ifndef BASECLASS_H
#define BASECLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class BaseClass
{
    std::string name;
    BaseClass* pParent = 0;
    std::vector<BaseClass*> children;

public:
    BaseClass(BaseClass* pParent = 0);
    BaseClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name);
    void setName(std::string name);
    std::string getName();
    void printTree();
};

#endif
```

RootClass.h

```
#ifndef ROOTCLASS_H
#define ROOTCLASS_H
#include "BaseClass.h"

class RootClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    RootClass();
    RootClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name);
};

#endif
```

ChildClass.h

```
#ifndef CHILDCLASS_H
#define CHILDCLASS_H
#include "BaseClass.h"

class ChildClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    ChildClass();
    ChildClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name);
};

#endif
```

Input data:
First line:
"Root object name"
A root object is created.

Second line and subsequent lines:
"Name of the head object" "name of the subordinate object"
A subobject is created and added to the hierarchical tree.

If the “name of the head object” equals the “name of the subordinate object”, then a new object is not created and the construction of the tree of objects is completed.

Input example:

```
Object_root
Object_root Object_1
Object_root Object_2
Object_root Object_3
Object_3 Object_4
Object_3 Object_5
Object_6 Object_6
```

Output:
First line:
"Root object name"

Second line and subsequent lines:
  the names of the head and
subordinate objects of the next level separated by two spaces.
“Name of the head object” “name of the subordinate object” [[“name of the subordinate object”] ........]

Output example:

```
Object_root
Object_root Object_1 Object_2 Object_3
Object_3 Object_4 Object_5
```

**Please help me understand where my mistake is. Thanks**

Comment: How is your output different from the expected output? Please add that to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, my program does not even start

Comment: So that's a compile error. Add the exact error messages, along with the line numbers to your question.

Comment: Aside: you don't need 3 classes here. `RootClass` and `ChildClass` are pointless. N.b. "ChildClass.cpp" is *identical* to "RootClass.cpp"

Comment: I think the problem is with null pointers, but if I remove them, only the first two objects will be displayed, and then the program stops its work

Comment: My error is Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Hmm, so your program compiles? If you have a runtime error, then you should learn how to use a debugger, it will be very helpful. If you still can't solve it yourself, then you need to describe *precisely* what is going wrong.

Comment: You might want to replace `cout` by `cerr`, even temporarily, because messages on `cout` may not yet be printed when your program crashes. `cerr` doesn't have this problem, so may be better for diagnostics of crashes.

Comment: You never add element's to the `children` of your root node, instead you constantly change its name.

Comment: Aside: `nullptr` is the preferred null pointer constant, not `0`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when moving the code here, I already fixed it, the debugger throws an error "An exception was thrown: read access violation. This was nullptr.". After I enter the name of the root object

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the behaviour of your constructor backwards. It should be

```
BaseClass::BaseClass(BaseClass* pParent, std::string name)
 : pParent(pParent), name(name)
{
    if (pParent)
        pParent->children.push_back(this);
}
```

Throw away `RootClass` and `ChildClass`. They discard their constructor parameters, and otherwise do nothing that `BaseClass` doesn't.

You also need to be able to find intermediate nodes. Something like

```
BaseClass * BaseClass::find(std::string name)
{
    if (name == this->name) return this;
    for (auto * child : children)
    {
         auto * found = child->find(name);
         if (found) return found;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then in `main`

```
while (cin >> parentName >> childName, parentName != childName)
{
    new BaseClass(root->find(parentName), childName);
}
```